# How can i put marker on map by using webservice

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, xml-serialization, sencha-touch, extjs

I Am New to in Sencha Touch2.0

I want to show a marker by using of xml file which is call in js and then this js call in Index.html file

Answer (score 0):

[Reading xml in sencha](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.XmlReader)

[Google Maps API Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"
  });
```

If you don't have latlng in your xml file you can use the geocoding api to turn addresses into lat [GeoCoding Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

Comment: but how can i pass my xml file path in js and also how to show some location marker on map.